# Programming the upgrade of Ubuntu at login session

Tags: bash, upgrade

Right after my login session, I would like Ubuntu to execute `sudo apt-get update & apt-get dist-upgrade` , systematically / automatically. The terminal must be opened so that I can see the output of each of these executions. In particular, I want to be asked to type "y/n" due to the command `apt-get dist-upgrade`. I don't want to have to type my password : thus, Ubuntu must use it as input of the `sudo` execution instead of me.

The modifications involved must be independant of any upgrade and migration of Ubuntu.

## Question

Which `bash` file should I edit and in which way ?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea. How would you login if something goes wrong.

Comment: However, you might setup the `/etc/sudoers` fille (using `visudo`) to disable the asking of a password. This would lower the security of your system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Startup-Application like descriped in the askuubuntu forum: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login#48327).

As command use

```
<your-terminal> -x sh -c "sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sleep 30"
```

So in your case for example

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sleep 30"
```

Afterwards the terminal should be opened and you have to enter your password.

**Edit:** Use sh -c "..." to get both commands run and the sleep command to prevent the terminal of closing immediately (read is not working here?)